# Understanding different kinds of RNGs tests

Tags: probability, random-generation

I'm studying different tests for uniform random number generators. I've read about the [diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) and [TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01). These tests test different properties of a uniform random number generator. The birthday test for instance, tests the uniformity of a random number generator, while the permutation test checks if values are correlated (if I understand it correctly).

**Question:** Is it possible to assign different tests for RNGs into different categories? And if so; which categories are there? Are there just uniformity and iid-ness?

Answer (score 2):

L'Ecuyer and Simard's paper at the TestU01 site divides TestU01's tests into categories that are more fine-grained than the categories into which Knuth divides them in *The Art of Computer Programming* 3rd ed., volume 2, chapter 3.  (Knuth divides them into three categories: empirical, theoretical, and spectral tests, which are both empirical and theoretical.)